# Why Android Database inserting wrong when onPause

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask

In my Project android i have a big data that i want insert to database.
I am using AsyncTask for inserting big data to database. for average 5 min needed to inserting.

But when my phone screen is off two bug exist.

```
1- for complete inserting the Screen must be On.  
2- if one or many time Screen will be off then database not good inserted.
```

`Question`

> > 1- where i am wrong.
> >     2- Other way to inserting big data to database

part of `My code`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DatabaseHandler db;
    MobileInformation   mobile;
    private          SetDataBaseTask    setDataBaseTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        mobile = new MobileInformation();
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String state = preferences.getString("IsSetDataBase","");
        if ( !state.equals("yes"))
        {
            setDataBaseTask=new setDataBaseTask();  
            setDataBaseTask.execute();
        }
    }

    public void firstDatabaseInitialize()
    {
            for (int i = 0;i < samsung0.brandStringList.length ; i++ )
            {
                mobile.Clean();
                mobile.Alert_types = samsung0.Alert_typesStringList[i];
                mobile.brand = samsung0.brandStringList[i];
                //and something other

                db.insertMobileInfo(mobile);
            }
                            //and many for for inserting
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if (Loading==true)
        {
            stopLoadingAndDownloading();
            if (setDataBaseTask != null && setDataBaseTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                setDataBaseTask.cancel(true);
        }
        db.close();
    }

    private class SetDataBaseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showLoading();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... esult) {
            String msg="";
            db.open();
            db.clearTable("indexing");
            db.clearTable("mobile");
            firstDatabaseInitialize();
            db.close();
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
            stopLoadingAndDownloading();    

             preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.putString("IsSetDataBase","yes");
             editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you take a wakelock??

Comment: My problem is when phone will go in onPause and Not only Screen off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`In my Project android i have a big data that i want insert to database.`

Then you could use an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) and when the insert is complete send a broadcast and the activity can register on that broadcast action (unregister is necessary as well) so it can display some UI updates.

`I am using AsyncTask for inserting big data to database. for average 5 min needed to inserting.`

I don't think it's a good idea, because on orientation changes you're screwed! Also, you will leak the parent activity for the duration of insertion. So moving the insertion to an `IntentService` will decouple the insertion from UI.